# Invalid expression term string in a method that accepts type as an argument

Tags: c#, expression

I am about to go crazy.

I can't figure out why this won't work.

```
Wrapper.DecompressAndDeserialize(string, ms);
```

Here is the overload for the method:

```
public static Object DecompressAndDeserialize(Type t, byte[] bytData)
    {
        byte[] b = Decompress(bytData);
        Object o = Deserialize(t, b);
        return o;
    }
```

I keep getting the error

```
Invalid expression term 'string'
```

I thought when I put in string, it knows it is the type string. I know it is probably a very simple answer, but I have hit a mental block.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this

```
Wrapper.DecompressAndDeserialize(typeof(string), ms);
```

Comment: I tried this before and it said the overloaded method was invalid, but after trying it again you made me realize that the assembly I am referencing targets a Silverlight framework and the program in which I am using it targets .NET 4.0. I think this is the real problem.

Thanks for the input. I'll probably end up posting a new question haha.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is just the *name* of the type. You want an expression of type `Type` - in other words, a reference to an instance of `Type` for the relevant type.

The simplest way to get that is with the [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator:

```
Wrapper.DecompressAndDeserialize(typeof(string), ms);
```

Another alternative would be to make the method generic:

```
public static T DecompressAndDeserialize<T>(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] b = Decompress(data);
    return (T) Deserialize(typeof(T), b);
}
```

And then call it as:

```
string x = Wrapper.DecompressAndDeserialize<string>(ms);
```

You could probably change the `Deserialize` method to be generic, too...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `typeof(string)` instead of `string`

```
Wrapper.DecompressAndDeserialize(typeof(string, ms);
```

See [typeof (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx)

> Used to obtain the **System.Type** object for a type.